# Credit Memo - custom refund amount per product

Tags: magento2, creditmemo, admin-order-create

I want to create Credit Memo with a custom amount per product. i.e. I do have 1st product with 100 price and 2nd product with 250 price.

Now when I create a Credit Memo I wanted to change the price from 100 to 70 and 250 to 150.

Can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance.